# Tools to reverse-engineer an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, modeling

I have at various times been asked to improve some predictive model whose only implementation and documentation is an Excel spreadsheet. What I want instead is a concise set of equations describing the model, of the sort you might see in an academic paper. Turning the former into the latter is a very tedious, painful, and error-prone process when done manually by clicking on cells, reading the formulas, and following the references.

Does anyone know of any good automatic tools for turning an Excel spreadsheet into a readable set of equations?

Comment: There are so many variables I douby there will be one. But hey, that's why you charge your clients, right?